# Is it reasonable to have weary character climb rope to safety?

Tags: characters, plot

My MC, injured (having been shot earlier) is extremely tired after carrying his partner, who took a bullet for him, towards safety.

She suspects that the ex-fil location they are heading towards might be compromised. Their adversaries are very clever and competent, so it is well within the field of possibility.

There is danger behind them as the hunt is on, danger ahead too. A safe place a quarter mile away is possible, but not without rest.

There is a hunting blind nearby with a ladder and a rope. 25 feet up is safer than on the ground as the search will surely find them there, but the adversaries need not think they went to ground by going up due to his injury.

My question is, considering he is extremely tired, is it credible to have him climb that rope which is the nearest path to safety?

Comment: Is there a ladder, or just a free hanging rope?

Comment: Both - an old wooden ladder and the free hanging rope. I was thinking their arms are the least compromised part so the rope might be the better method - can’t risk a groan with danger so close

Comment: A ladder will be a huge help for anyone if the legs are at least a bit functioning. And it would be very odd for the chasing party to dismiss a hiding place with a ladder leading to it.

Comment: To directly answer your question - all depends on your MC. If he's fit like Navy Seal or American Ninja, he'll do it. An average person is unlikely to be able to climb 25 feet without any leg support.

Comment: Problem is he was wounded in the torso, so using his legs to climb would be very painful and run the risk of less than silence. He is extremely fit, but wounded.

Comment: If his legs are not working, how is he able to move across terrain?

Comment: This seems more like a question for a site that looks at physiology and other science.  I'd say Worldbuilding, though it might not be buildy enough for there.

Comment: His legs are workimg, but the motion of climbing a ladder would require the use of the injured area, so would be almost prohibitively painful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the craft of writing.

Comment: Wounded in the torso might mean he cannot pull himself up by rope. Muscles compressed by gravity is painful but he can obviously walk, but reversing the stress on those same areas (pull instead of push, stretch instead of compress) could be fantastically painful and lead to opening the wound, internal bleeding, etc.

Comment: @Cyn it could pass on Worldbuilding under the reality check tag, I think. Something along the line of "is it plausible to have an injured character to climb a rope".

Comment: @Liquid that sounds reasonable.  I'll support it there.

Comment: @wetcircuit That is a valid point that essentially answers my question. If he made it up the rope and died that would not work.

Answer (score 3):

You are better off with the ladder; it is easy to climb a ladder using only one good leg, if your arms are functional. The other leg can be completely broken. Just use your hands and arms to hold up ALL your weight while you move the good leg to the next step, dragging the injured leg without any pressure, until you are inside.

You best pull the ladder up after you, any person-hunter that doesn't investigate a **ladder** leading to a **treehouse** as a potential hiding place has a brain injury.

If you want to get rid of the ladder and use just a rope, Don't use the Gym class method, use the Navy Seal Brake and Squat BUD/s [Basic Underwater Demolition / Seals] method shown on this site. There is a 3:52 video at the bottom of the blog post; the BUD/s Brake and Squat starts at 2:00, and the soldier there climbs about 30 feet.
[How To Climb A Rope Like A Navy Seal](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-climb-a-rope-like-a-navy-seal/).

The thing to note here is that all the body weight is supported on one good leg and the two arms; the bad leg probably can't be broken here, it is used but no serious pressure is put on it. Since your injured man can cross terrain, I presume his leg is not actually shattered.

For those that cannot see the video; the BUD/s method is illustrated below; it comes from that site and is from ITS Tactical. In this picture all the weight is on the arms and climber's right leg. The rope travels under the right boot then over the left boot, which acts as a brake so the climber doesn't slip down the rope. The "squat" part of this is to support the body completely with the arms, pull the legs up into a squat, then step on the rope and bring the hands higher on it.

[image: Brake And Squat BUD/s Style]

For a thinner rope, it is possible to do something similar wrapping it around the good leg a few times. It is much more awkward but doable. If the left leg is really bad, imagine taking that loop over the left boot, and bringing it up into the left **hand**. Then you can hang on to the rope with your right hand, pick your right foot up about a foot or two, tighten the rope underneath it with your left hand and stand, scooting your hands on the ropes. It is also awkward, but it can work.

Like the ladder, pull the rope up behind you.

In general, if the blind is not very well camouflaged, their adversaries are just not going to be fooled. I think you are making them too stupid; they aren't deer, and they probably don't know **exactly** how bad their prey is injured, or whether the guy can climb **to save his life.** The adversaries are going to put some bullets into that blind if they see it, not just turn their back on it and say "Oh well, they vanished."

If possible, I'd use the blind ***as*** a blind, and if the adversaries approach, shoot to kill. Or use it as a lure: Station your men in cover on the ground, so when the adversaries find the blind, and shoot it up, and climb to investigate it, they are ambushed by sniper fire from the ground in a crossfire. You get more weapons and ammo.

Comment: That is a very good technique and I bookmarked the site. You certainly have a point regarding the competent pursuit. I gave myself a small problem when I decided both ‘sides’ have to know what they are doing.